Is there a way to scale my speed variable with the screen resolution?
I have a resizable window, as well as a projectile that can be shot from a cannon, with a speed depending on the framerate and elapsed time. The calculations are done in the following code with SFML.
if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Space) && !shoot) {
    shoot = true;
}

// Calculate bomb radians
bombRadians = ((2.f * PI / 360.f) * bomb.getRotation());
x = bombSpeed * sin(bombRadians);
y = bombSpeed * -cos(bombRadians);

if (shoot) {
    bomb.move(x, y);
}

// Timer
frames++;
if (frames == 6) {
    timer += 0.1f * (60 / framerate);
    frames = 0;
}
cout << timer << '\n';
// Update speeds
playerSpeed = (timer / 90.f + 1.f) * (60.f / framerate);
bombSpeed = ((timer / 25.f + 2.f) / 2.f + 6.f) * (60.f / framerate);

I want to be able to resize the window and have the speed scale with the resolution so the cannonball clears the screen in the same amount of time no matter the resolution.
// Simplified versions of the calculations
timer += 6.f / framerate;
bombSpeed = ((6.f * timer) + 2100.f) / (5.f * framerate);
planeSpeed = ((6.f * timer) + 300.f) / (5.f * framerate);


You don't show what happens to the position of the bomb or how bombSpeed is used ..?

@Botje I updated the question

speed = distance / time. So you decide on a time (duration) of how long you want your animation to be, you get your distance from your position and resolution and you have your speed.

and can you tell me how to calculate that given the equations i provided?

Set up all your game logic using normalized co-ordinates, and then apply a transformation at the time of drawing. For example, you might choose (-a/2, -0.5) and (a/2, 0.5) as the top-left and bottom-right logical co-ordinates where a is the aspect ratio width/height. Then, when you draw, you scale all positions and sizes by height and add (width, height) to all positions. Your built-in constants for speeds and internal state for positions, object sizes etc should all be based on the logical resolution assuming a screen height of 1 unit. That way you are independent of display size.

can you please explain your logic for timer, player and bomb speed?

@paddy I'd rather have a more practical way of doing this, like multiplying the speed by a quadratic or linear function. I already have my own ways to scale sprites to the screen, so I don't want to mess with that.

@kiner_shah The timer works by adding 0.1 every 6 frames (assuming 60 fps), and it can scale the timer to your framerate using (60/framerate). The player speed is a linear function based on the time elapsed/90, making it increase slowly, and adding 1 as a starting speed. The bomb speed is just arbitrary numbers that work fine. I have a simplified version that i'll add to the end of the question. By the way, I just simplified the equations using Google to remove the human error margin, so I can't really explain what the numbers represent afterwards,

If you just want a scaling factor, then take whatever "base" resolution you've designed your equation for, and the "actual" resolution. Your scaling factor is then actual / base. By "resolution", I mean whatever value makes sense. As I mentioned before, you typically account for aspect ratio and use a single value to drive everything. Usually the vertical resolution.

More generally, your timer setup here is going to break down eventually due to floating point precision errors. You shouldn't drive your equations that way. Instead, you should incorporate some kind of "elapsed" time between frames and adjust for any error there. In other words, drive things off relative time (i.e. deltas) instead of absolute. If you use a single value that keeps increasing over time, it won't take long for the whole thing to fall apart.

@paddy How long does that take? Because I ran the program for 2 hours next to a stopwatch and it was off sync by about 10 seconds when I came back.

You could be out of sync for other reasons too. I doubt your framerate assumptions are precise, and you may also be dropping frames. I'm talking about numeric breakdown due to the number of fractional bits available in floating point values. Depending on the application that can become a problem as early as 5 significant figures (base 10). However, it's unclear if this really affects you. If timer is reset when you fire the bomb, that's fine. On a separate note, it is quite unusual that the bomb seems to be driven by a circle equation, not a parabola.... Is it in orbit?

@paddy The timer doesn't reset, but I know my framerate calculations are fine for what I'm doing. Also the bomb is in orbit around the cannon.

If you're interested, here's a simple test to run increments of 0.1 until the error between increments degrades above 1%. That takes 650k iterations. It then shows the total error by calculating what the final timer should have been, and it's out by 400, which means an error of 4000 iterations. That's because of compound errors causing drift at every single iteration. That's an inherent problem with using float as a counter.
